# Create subdomain from a folder, but deny folder access

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay, I've spent almost 4 hours searching the site for a solution, and another 2 hours searching google, wich is not quite useful when most sites copy paste the data. So here I decided to ask for a little help.

I created a subdomain successfully, let's say `http://admin.myhost.com`, wich basically take the data from the folder `admin`. The problem is that when I put `http://myhost.com/admin` the scripts are still accessible. Let's say I want to make this folder unaccessible, throwing a redirect to a custom file, for example `index.php?template=error404` when some file is executed via the url `http://myhost.com/admin`. I've added this line to the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) /index.php?template=error404 [L]
```

and it ended up like this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?map=google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?map=google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download(.*) /index.php?template=error404 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) /index.php?template=error404 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?seo_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It actually works only if I delete the empty `.htaccess` on the admin folder (It only says RewriteEngine on), but when I do that, the site `http://admin.myhost.com` throws an http error 500, and it is not accessible anymore. If I add again the `.htaccess` on the admin folder stating the RewriteEngine on rule, the subdomain starts to work again, but again, the folder is accessible via URL adding `/admin`

I can't seem to find the solution to this problem after several hours. Is there any way to do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried by simply making index.php file in that (admin) folder. and write only just only line out there 
header("Location:any page url"); so it will redirect it. When some body access admin folder...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `/admin/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block access if HOSTNAME is not starting with admin.    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

OR if you want to show /index.php?template=error404 then

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?template=error404 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank god, I actually edited the last line to redirect to the custom 404 error, wich actually grabs the remote address and add the database all the errors, requested uri, time, url, browser, and other data, and that's why I needed to be redirected instead of protected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out, whenever SO allows you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yup, I was waiting to be allowed to mark it, thanks a lot again, now my headache is slowly fading out...

Comment: Thanks and I upvoted your question too. Nicely drafted question with lot of details.